# Does java usually take up all this memory in development?

Tags: java, eclipse, memory, intellij-idea, ram

how much RAM do I need to develop java comfortably?

Sorry if my question seems stupid, but I have been developing java for a while on my laptop... it has 3GB ram with 2 GB Swap... I work on gnu/linux Kubuntu 32 bit 11.10, and sun JVM 6.

After using eclipse with a couple of applications like Firefox and chrome open... in many cases if I compile with maven... it ends up taking all Memory available with all swap.... to the point where the kernel auto kills the processes.

I can't understand what it's doing with a full 3.5 GB of Memory (assuming the others use 1.5 GB)??? Usually just eclipse or IntelliJ takes about 1.5 GB....

Is this just me? Do java and eclipse actually require all this memory? Am doing something wrong? I have been working for years on Dotnet and mono on a 1.2 GB ram machine and I was fine...

Thanks a lot.

Comment: problem is Chrome and Firefox are becoming a couple of memory hogs

Comment: True, but I use the same machine with the same configuration with mono and It works normally....

Comment: There are a variety of ways to evaluate what is taking up memory (for example, procexp.exe).  Without you showing us such information, there is absolutely no way we're going to be able be of any help.

Comment: I just want to know if other users of eclipse or Intellij find that after a while, it uses that much ram...

Comment: I am looking for an answer like: "from my experience, I develop java comfortably and it usually takes no more than  on x MB of ram"

Comment: Eclipse - Real Mem : 512 MB, Virtual Mem : 1024 MB
Chrome (around 30 tabs) - Real Mem : 1900 MB, Virtual Mem : 3000 MB

Comment: @AhHatem: With 3GB you shouldn't have any issue.  300 KLOC Java codebase here, under IntelliJ IDEA and I limit IDEA's mem to 512 MB (-Xmx512m in *idea.vmoptions*).  Because browsers are so insecure I never **ever** consider running them in something else than a VM.  So I've got a 768 MB KVM virtual machine to run Chrome.  The side benefit (besides security) of running any *"browser-the-insecure-pig"* in a VM is that if it becomes too bloated to the point the kernel has to free mem, it does so in the VM running your (ever insecure) browser. All this on a 5 years old Core 2 Duo with 4 GB of Ram.

Comment: @AhHatem: to answer to your comment: I do develop in Java on Linux on a 300KLOC codebase very comfortably under IntelliJ IDEA and IDEA **never** takes more than 512 MB of mem because I force IDEA to never use more than 512 MB : )

Comment: @user988052: Thanks for the suggestion... I will consider limiting their memory..

Comment: @AhHatem: be careful that Eclipse may be more memory hungry than IntelliJ IDEA...

Comment: I never run an ide under 1g ram; not worth it. in my experience, eclipse uses more memory than intellij. Both can cope with a large (250kloc) project, but eclipse will start chunking depending on your plugin usage. 2g provides a lot more breathing room.

Comment: Ok .. Seems like 1.5 gb for eclipse is not that weired after all..

Comment: @Dave Newton" *"I never run an ide under 1g ram; not worth it"*... It really depends if you like longer GC pause or not etc. For a medium Java codebase around 300KLOC (that's not anywhere near a big codebase btw) I've got absolutely no issue with 512 MB or RAM for IntelliJ. It also leaves more memory for the rest of the OS/app, which is also important.  I take it that YMMV but saying that *"it's not worth it"* when most people aren't even working on codebase with hundreds of KLOC is a bit misleading IMHO.  Once again: Linux + 512 MB of Ram for IntelliJ + 300 KLOC .java: totally fine.  YMMV : )

Comment: @user988052 I don't see similar performance on my Linux box with IntelliJ.

Comment: Well, my personal experience is that IntelliJ is a little better than eclipse, Knowing that I use eclipse with sprincesource tools, gwt plugin, and a dozen others... 
And I work on a code base of about 400KLOC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I typically give eclipse about 1.5GB auf RAM, because it is faster with more memory available.

But it seldom actually uses that.

What might be happening is that you have a memory leak in your application. If you redeploy over and over again cruft might pile up. Check if restarting the server make any difference.

Of course since eclipse is just a bag plugins, there might be a specific plugin that causes trouble. You could try and look at your eclipse with visualvm.

Comment: I didn't know about visualvm.. I will try to use it to track the issue... but I don't think it is in my app... I actually use GWT internal jetty and I frequently stop restart it.